# How to escape dash in jq call

Tags: jq

How to escape dash in jq call?

```
cat afile | jq -r .commit-sha1
```

So the dash is being interpreted in some way. How to escape it? I tried wrap with "

Comment: Can you share the content of the `afile`, the expected output and the output that you're getting now?

Comment: Put double quotes around field names with "special" characters. To avoid that these quotes are interpreted by the shell, put single quotes around the whole filter: `jq -r '."commit-sha1"' afile`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For such keys, you need to quote the key, but the quotes must *also* be quoted so that they aren't removed by the shell prior to running `jq`.

```
jq -r '."commit-sha1"'
```

The abbreviated from `.foo` is for "simple, identifier-like keys", according to the man page.